# Why is class type missing after serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I faced with jackson`s known issue about "Missing type information on Serialization"(http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization)
And I can't understand it.
Why does this work fine(class type sets correctly)?

```
@Path("{id}")
@GET
public List<POJO> getPOJO(@PathParam("id") BigInteger id) {
    //get some pojoInstances from db
    List<POJO> arr = new ArrayList<>(pojoInstances);
    return arr;
}
```

And that one doesn't work

```
@Path("{id}")
@GET
public Collection<POJO> getPOJO(@PathParam("id") BigInteger id) {
    //get some pojoInstances from db
    return new ArrayList<>(pojoInstances);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not enough to be sure of the root cause, but as a general rule it is likely due to Java Type Erasure. A simple way to avoid this class of problems is to never use generic type is the root value; that is, immediate value to serialize or deserialize by REST API. Instead it is better to have a POJO which may freely contain generic types such as `List`s and `Map`s. This avoids most problems with polymorphic type information handling.

Alternative way to avoid generic root types is to use Java arrays instead: in this case, `POJO[]`. Arrays are fully typed, not using generics, and as such type information is always available from instances.